# QListView internal move without serialization

Tags: qt, qlistview

I'm trying to support rearranging a list of large objects in a QListView. It seems that the model/view framework insists on serializing the items which, in this case, is highly inefficient. I've tried to shorten things by using shared_ptr's, so only one bit of data needs passing, but even so, it feels very messy and is not at all reliable.

Worse still, during the move I notice the serialization functions are called repeatedly (dozens/hundreds of times). Surely they should only be called once each.

I'm sure I'm missing a trick, what's the correct way to achieve simple, internal move, list ordering without heavy serialize overhead?

```cpp
class Big
{
public:
  Big();
  ~Big();

  ...
};

using BigPtr = std::shared_ptr<Big>;

Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(BigPtr) // and qRegisterMetaTypeStreamOperators

// Required serialization operators
// This is very ugly, and what I want rid of...
QDataStream &operator<<(QDataStream &out, const BigPtr &big)
{
    qDebug() << "Out <<";

    out << (quint64)big.get();
    return out;
}
// ...This too...
QDataStream &operator>>(QDataStream &in, BigPtr &big)
{
    qDebug() << "In >>";

    quint64 raw = 0;
    in >> raw;
    li.reset((LayerPtr::element_type *)raw);

    return in;
}

class BigModel : public QAbstractListModel
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    BigModel (std::vector<BigPtr> &bigs, QObject *parent = Q_NULLPTR);

    int rowCount(const QModelIndex &parent = QModelIndex()) const;
    QVariant data(const QModelIndex &index, int role = Qt::DisplayRole) const;
    Qt::ItemFlags flags(const QModelIndex &index) const;  // Qt::ItemIsDragEnabled or Qt::ItemIsDropEnabled depending on valid index
    Qt::DropActions supportedDropActions() const;  // return Qt::MoveAction
    bool setData(const QModelIndex &index, const QVariant &value, int role = Qt::EditRole);
    bool insertRows(int row, int count, const QModelIndex &parent = QModelIndex());
    bool removeRows(int row, int count, const QModelIndex &parent = QModelIndex());

private:
    std::vector<BigPtr> &_bigs;
};

...

    // dialog setup...
    ui->listView->setSelectionMode(QAbstractItemView::SingleSelection);
    ui->listView->setSelectionBehavior(QAbstractItemView::SelectRows);
    ui->listView->setEditTriggers(QAbstractItemView::DoubleClicked);
    ui->listView->setDragEnabled(true);
    ui->listView->setDragDropMode(QAbstractItemView::InternalMove);
    ui->listView->setDropIndicatorShown(true);
    ui->listView->viewport()->setAcceptDrops(true);
```

EDIT:

After more head scratching, I decided to overload the `mimeData` and `dropMimeData` functions and sub-class `QMimeData` to carry the `BigPtr` directly.

```cpp
class BigMimeData : public QMimeData
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    BigMimeData(const QVariant &_big)
         : big(_big)
    { }
    bool hasFormat(const QString &/*mimeType*/) const { return true; }


    QVariant big;
};

...

QMimeData *BigModel::mimeData(const QModelIndexList &indexes) const
{
    if(indexes.count() > 0) {
        return new BigMimeData(indexes.at(0).data());
    }

    return Q_NULLPTR;
}

bool BigModel::dropMimeData(const QMimeData *data, Qt::DropAction action,
                              int row, int /*column*/, const QModelIndex &parent)
{
    if(!data || !(action == Qt::CopyAction || action == Qt::MoveAction)) {
        return false;
    }

    // start of list
    if(row == -1) {
        row = rowCount(parent);
    }

    auto dragged = static_cast<const BigMimeData *>(data);

    // setData with stored value
    insertRow(row, parent);
    setData(index(row, 0, parent), dragged->big);

    return true;
}
```

Which works, but seriously!? All that just to enable simple list reordering in the UI? It can't be this complex surely?

BTW, a lot of these answer seem to be focusing on the underlying data structure, that's not the question. The problem is that simple internal move drag/drop rearrangement in a list control seem to be ridiculously complex in `QListView` because it requires costly serialization. It's a UI/Widgets/MVC question.

Comment: I would likely recommend using a `std::list` with a custom allocator that preallocates a large amount of memory (obviously, test it to see if it works, I could be **way** off). This makes internal rearrangements `O(1)`, the preallocated memory gives cache benefits and performance improvements, and allows you to avoid a lot of the performance limitations of Qt's containers. That said, likely lazy loading of the UI via `canFetchMore` and `fetchMore` will likely also be useful.

Comment: Unfortunately, if it needs the serialization functions to set the data on the view (`Qt::DisplayRole`), it may call them every single time the widget needs repainting (which is very frequent).

Comment: One year had passed and still no answer here... Really, is there no way to reorder model internally without serialization? Yes, I know that you can subclass `QListView` and override `dropEvent`, but that's an overkill also.